# Android default printscreen override

Tags: android

Hi I am totaly new in creating android app. I just installed android studio. On my phone (nexus 5) , when I press power button and volume, then printscreen is made. Is this possible to override this action ? like also make this printscreen but add some postprocessing of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible to override this action ?

No, sorry.

> like also make this printscreen but add some postprocessing of it ?

On Android 5.0 and higher, [you can take your own screenshot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent%28%29) (with user permission), then post-process that, if you like.

Comment: and what about SDK 15 ?

Comment: @kosnkov: Outside of rooted devices, you have no means of capturing a screenshot, let alone post-processing it.

Comment: so it woudn't be possible to implement a program which runs in bacground of some game in android, doing pritnscreens parsing and clicking for player ?

Comment: @kosnkov: At best, you might be able to do that on Android 5.0 and higher, or for gamers that have rooted their devices.

Comment: I am wondering why google change their mind in this, that now they allow for this